# Better Way to retrieve column column wise data for multiple rows using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to get column-wise data(`ArrayList` of every column data) from DB table using `JdbcTemplate` Object, which contains multiple rows let say 100 rows.
I Have tried with below code snippet

```
Qry = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
List<Employee> listData= jdbcTemplate.query(Qry,
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class));
```

Using the above code I can get `List<Employee>` and I created `ArrayList` Objects for every column and inserted into that for every iteration, But unfortunately I have 35 columns.
So is there any better solution can I get.

Comment: specify your column names in the `select` sql

Answer (score 1):

you can use ResultSetExtractor for this purpose, just providing a small snippet

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    jdbcTemplate.query(Qry, new ResultSetExtractor() {

        @Override
        public Object extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            resultSet.getArray(int columnIndex); //use this array or convert to List if you need
        }
    });
```

You need to take this forward

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Tq for your response ...but if we go through java doc regarding getArray() methosd is: Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as an Array object in the Java programming language. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @PraveenKesani you can use that object to create any other object that you want